# How to Ignore properties for Db not for instance in ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

```
public class Message
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(UserAuth))]
    public int FromId { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public UserName FromUserName {get;set;}

 }
```

When I use "Ignore" attribute framework Ignores the property during messaging. How can I write "Ignore it for Db persistance but don't ignore it messaging (serialization)". Or do I have to write new class for it.

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't be using your entities for anything other than Db access. If you want to pass them to a UI, use them in a model, etc... You should create an _almost_ identical DTO (Data Transfer Object). AutoMapper can help in converting one to the other

Comment: Yes, I know DTOs but only for one field it seems so DRY (dont repeat yourself) killer. Actually, the field is not UserName it is UserAuth class. It is the convention that I try to implement. (Foreign Key for persistance and Class for real time usage).

Comment: I completely understand - I've lost count of the projects I've started determined to avoid DTOs and yet I always seem to need them (Return a list of users without password hashes/salts, summary information, etc.). I've even tried auto-generation of classes based on custom attributes. If you do find a decent solution, I'd like to see it.

Comment: i have all items like this in a BaseModel  and your model inherits the base model with all properties of ignore.   you get the extra values in a view model sense but does not effect your poco.    i use this to add paging, pagenow  etc to each and every model, so out of the box, every result has the paging properties i always use!   for other examples just use another base model, or you could also use partials, so that you can extend your model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for now. Using Automapper can disburden.